# assembly, bad array filling from one function to another

Tags: c, arrays, assembly, x86, att

The assembly functions with commented c version:

```
/*
int f (int x) 
{ 
    return x+2; 
}

void map2 (int* um, int * outro, int n) 
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
      *(outro+i) = f(*(um+i));
}
*/

.text

.globl f
f:
/********************************** prologue *************************************/
    pushl   %ebp        
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %ebx        
/********************************************************************************/

    movl    8(%ebp), %eax   /* eax receives x value             */
    addl    $2, %eax         /* return x+2;                      */

/************************************** end *************************************/
    popl    %edi
    popl    %ebx
    movl    %ebp, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
/*********************************************************************************/

.globl map2
map2:
/********************************** prologue *************************************/
    pushl   %ebp        
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %ebx
    pushl   %esi
    pushl   %edi            
/********************************************************************************/

    movl    $0, %ebx         /* i = 0; INIT                     */
L1: cmpl    16(%ebp), %ebx  /* if (!(i<n))                     */
    jge     out     

    movl    12(%ebp), %esi  /* esi receives 'outro' (another) address   */
    **movl  %ebx, %ecx      /* moves ebx value for bytes multiplication */
    imul    $4, %ecx         /* 4(int) * i bytes to course          */**
    addl    %ecx, %esi      /* esi points to outro+i                    */

    movl    8(%ebp), %edi   /* edi receives 'um' (one) address          */
    **movl  %ebx, %edx      /* moves ebx value for bytes multiplication */
    imul    $4, %edx         /* 4(int) * i bytes to course          */**
    addl    %edx, %edi      /* edi points to um+i                       */ 

/************************ calls f and return it's value *************************/
    pushl   %ecx
    pushl   %edx
    pushl   %eax

    pushl   (%edi)          /* push *(um+i) for 'f' usage           */
    call    f
    movl    %eax, (%esi)    /* *(outro+i) = f(*(um+i));             */
    addl    $4, %esp         /* clears *(um+i) from stack            */

    popl    %eax
    popl    %edx
    popl    %ecx
/********************************************************************************/

    incl    %ebx            /* i++;                     */
    jmp     L1              /* end loop                 */

out:
/************************************** end *************************************/
    popl    %edi
    popl    %esi
    popl    %ebx
    movl    %ebp, %esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
/********************************************************************************/
```

The main C Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10

int f (int x);
void map2 (int* um, int * outro, int n);

int main (void) {
    int i;
    int a[N], b[N];

    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        a[i] = i;
        printf("b[%d] = %d\n", i, f(i));    // added for debug purposes
    }

    map2(a,b,N);
    printf("\n");                           // added for clear sight

    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
        printf("b[%d] = %d\n", i, b[i]);

    return 1;
}
```

output:

```
b[0] = 2
b[1] = 3
b[2] = 4
b[3] = 5
b[4] = 6
b[5] = 7
b[6] = 8
b[7] = 9
b[8] = 10
b[9] = 11
```

```
b[0] = 33686018 
b[1] = 33686019 
b[2] = 516 
b[3] = -253 
b[4] = -145333866 
b[5] = -143814668 
b[6] = -145333723 
b[7] = -143596928  
b[8] = 0 
b[9] = 134513961
```

```
<seg fault>
```

Pretty clear that the 'f' function is ok, however 'map2' has some problem. From b[4] to b[7] getting memory junk. What's wrong here?
My guess is something about `popl %edi` `popl %esi` at the end of the code, since they're holding the two arrays addresses. Even so, changes there didn't fix the problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem here. :/

Comment: what you mean? It goes well in your machine? ._.

Comment: Yes. I get the same output for the two runs. i.e `map2` works correctly.

Comment: Then it's even odder than I already thought o_o

Comment: No, your `f` is **not ok**. It has a `pop %edi` but it never pushed `%edi`. The `mov %ebp, %esp` will fix the stack imbalance it caused, but it will nevertheless destroy `edi` that the caller depends upon.

Comment: Perfect @Jester. Bad code reuse of mine.